# Most efficient way to store timestamps for time series data in a text file?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I want to save and read time series data to and from CSV files. Each file will have tens of thousands of rows. I will probably use pandas for reading. What would be the most performance effective way to store timestamps? ISO formatted datetime: `2018-03-10T04:05:46.100Z`, UNIX epoch time: `1520733691418` or something else?

Comment: Are you more interested in saving space or saving read time or write time?

Comment: Saving read/parsing time I think is the most important factor.

Comment: I feel like using an actual time series database would make more sense than a plain file